# Android data persistence (Room) with different accounts

Tags: persistence, android-room, android-architecture-components, user-accounts

Let's assume I have a project similar to the google sample code:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components
I want to add an account system to the app. How can I persist data and make the following scenario work:

1. go to persistent-data-fragment and load data from backend
2. log out
3. log into a different account
4. go to that same fragment

As a result, I should not be able to see the first user's data and instead load them from backend for the second user. How to use Room for that?

Answer (score 0):

It a generic question, so I can answer with a generic answer :).

1 - on the server side you need to authenticate a user that access to REST services. There are many ways to do this. JWT is a good solution. Start reading [this article](https://medium.com/emblatech/secure-your-spring-restful-apis-with-jwt-a-real-world-example-bfdd2679db5f).

2 - on the client side, probably you need to introduce in your database a user table and link other database's entities to user identity. Using Room you have to declare a user bean and then link them to other room entities.

I hope it helps.